# array of integers with 1000 elements (1to1000) in random order

Tags: .net, arrays, function, random, integer

New to programming
I want to write a function that returns an array of integers with 1000 elements containing the values 1 to 1000 in random order.

```
private static void RandomNum()
    {
        //Initialize an array
        int[] randomList = new int[1000];
        //Initialize an instance of random class
        Random rnd = new Random();
        // integer variable
        int counter = 0;



            while (counter < 1000)
            {
                //store random num 
                int random = rnd.Next(1, 1001);


                if (Array.IndexOf(randomList, random) <= 0)
                {
                    //store random number into Array
                    randomList[counter] = random;
                    counter++;
                }

            }


        //output elements in Array
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(randomList[i]);
        }
        //output number of elements in Array
        Console.WriteLine(counter);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This should get you started http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `Array.IndexOf(randomList, random) <= 0` seems to be a bug since it includes zero which is a valid index (the first). If the code is intended to avoid duplicates it will fail on all random numbers that are equal to the first. Instead you could use `< 0` or `!randomList.Contains(random)`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Nice catch. 

Is there a reason an array is being used rather than a list? If list was being used, you could do List.Contains(random) and avoid duplicates that way.

Comment: @PWilliams0530: you can still use `Enumerable.Contains`(as commented). I don't know why he needs an array but since he wants 1000 random numbers the size is known and an array seems to be appropriate.

Comment: Not Sure where the posters skill level is (as they say they are new to programming) - but check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561742/generate-distinct-random-numbers-in-c-sharp

Comment: Its also worth saying that this is not the best way to generate this list. The best way would be using a Knuth shuffle which in essence takes an array and then loops through each element chooses a random position and then swaps those two. This will end up with each element in a random position and only needs n random numbers whereas the above in a really unlucky case could not terminate at all!

Comment: thanks for the responses, really appreciate them. I should use Knuth shuffle then? I was given this assignment where only Random rnd=new Random() & rnd.Next(1,1000) are the only classes i should use outside of the intrinsic data types (i.e. no collections).

Comment: @Beetle: You can do the knuth shuffle with that. Its much better because for your method when you only have a few numbers left to fill in then you will be generating loads of numbers that you already have and thus looping through far more than you need to. Back of the envelope calculation says you will probably be generating at least 50,000 random numbers to get your random list.

Answer (score 4):

This checks if the number `random` generated by `rnd.Next(1, 1001)` exists in the array `randomList`. If it does not exist then it stores it in the array `randomList` in the index specified by the `counter`.

If you would like to generate some random ordering you could use a bit of LINQ:

```
private static void RandomNum()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    var randomList = Enumerable.Range(1,1000)
        .OrderBy(x=>rnd.Next(1,1000))
        .ToArray();

    foreach(var item in randomList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    //output number of elements in Array
    Console.WriteLine(randomList.Count());
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: I do not think so as `Enumerable.Range(1,1000)` will ensure that we get 1000 different values. Then i rank them randomly using `order = rnd.Next(1,1000)` but i only use this in the order by. Though `rnd.Next(1,1000)` may produce the exact same number for two values, this will only mean that they will be one next to the other. No duplication there.

Comment: No need to .Select(x => x)

Comment: Yeap... This was left from a previous edit where i was actually generating an `order` property that would be used to order by it and then selecting only the result of the Range. I have already removed them as unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

A lazy man's way to a random ordering would be to just do:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).OrderBy(x=>System.Guid.NewGuid());
```

It's not necessarily a *good* randomization, but it *is* random.

Another way that's more random, but with slightly higher space/time requirements would be:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).ToList();
var randomizedNumbers = new List<int>();
while (numbers.Count > 0)
{
    var removeIndex = rnd.Next(0, numbers.Count - 1);
    var number = numbers[removeIndex];
    randomizedNumbers.Add(number);
    numbers.RemoveAt(removeIndex);
}
```

This just continually pulls a random number out of the first list and puts it into a new collection, until the first list is empty.

Or, as others have said, the *best* way is to use a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how Guids are generated but assuming they are as random as `Random.Next` is then it is probably better than the above since it is more efficient.

Comment: @Chris The GUID trick is neat and will probably be good enough in most cases, but it is less efficient than Fisher-Yates.

Fisher-Yates is O(n) when implemented properly, while the .OrderBy in the GUID trick is going to do a comparison sort, which is O(n log n).

Comment: @Techrocket9: Yup. Agreed. I'm no longer sure what I was referring to by "the above" but I assume I meant the original post. I suspect I was also trying to make a point that it is still a "good randomization" in that it will be as random as anything else as long as the GUIDs are generated as randomly.